# Tomcat, no data from Result set?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, jdbc

I'm having trouble getting any sense back from my mySQL database. I'm passing it a valid query that should return a single row. However it only ever returns me 0, the intial value of `int results`

```
public String getResultSet(String query) throws SQLException{
            ResultSet rs = null;
            int results=0;
            try {
                con = ds.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    while(rs.next()){                   
                        results = rs.getInt("location_id");             
                    }           

                } catch (Exception ex ){               
            } finally {
                if (con != null) con.close();
            }           
            return Integer.toString(results);           
        }
```

No errors are being thrown, could some advise what I'm doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: have you tried with the debugger to see if you actually enter the while loop with the rs.next() ?

Comment: Have you run the query in your DB and verified that it returns results?

Comment: Yes the query is valid, it does enter the while loop. Do you think the code looks valid then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a catch block for `Exception` with an empty body.  This will catch and silently ignore any SQL etcetera exceptions.  Then you will drop out of the try/catch, and return `results` ... which will still be zero.

---

What you are doing is "squashing" the exception; i.e. catching it and throwing it away without doing any recovery or error reporting.  This is **bad practice**.  Worse still, you are doing this for `Exception`.  That means you are doing it not only for the checked exceptions that you (possibly) expect to occur, but also for a whole range of unchecked exceptions that you cannot anticipate.

Comment: There is just no action on the catch, that is all. I don't see how that could effect the ResultSet?

Comment: @Eric Banderhide What if there's an exception thrown ? You wouldn't even know if something were wrong if you have an empty catch clause.

Comment: Where does the exception print to on Tomcat, is it Catalina.out?

Comment: I added the stack trace, went and had a look and it pointed me to the error. It was the cast of the Statement that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No exceptions are being thrown because you are catching them all without printing them. If there are any, you'd never see them because your catch block is empty.